# Laravel Socialite can't login with apple

Tags: php, ios, laravel, flutter, laravel-socialite

I try to add Log in With Apple in my Flutter App With Laravel Backend.
In Flutter I use [sign_in_with_apple: ^4.1.0](https://pub.dev/packages/sign_in_with_apple) for generate identityToken, and now I Have to Get User Data With Laravel so I use Socialite & socialiteproviders/apple with this syntax:

```
Socialite::driver('apple')->userFromToken($accessToken);
```

But this error show to me I don't know why ?!

```
"message": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response::setContent(): Argument #1 ($content) must be of type ?string, SocialiteProviders\\Manager\\OAuth2\\User given, called in /home/My_DOMAIN/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php on line 72",
```

any idea how I could fix this ??

Comment: did you find a solution for that problem ? @Michel E Ibrahim